# Trigger off Event added via Outlook Side Panel -

Tags: trigger, event, salesforce-for-outlook

I have a trigger to feed to Chatter Event activities. It predates Salesforce's chattering of activites and I'd like to keep it.

It works when I use the manual web interface. Upon investigating  debugs now the WhatId is blank during the trigger run but when I pull the event later in the Excel Connector, the WhatId is not blank - it has been associated.

The trigger runs after insert and associates via the field WhatId - what I need to use. AccountId field is also blank during the trigger run.

Any suggestions?
Do I need to run a batch after this, later than the 'after insert"?
How can the event be inserted and associated but return a null WhatId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to have the trigger check to see if WhoId and WhatId were both NULL.  If so, the trigger would pass the event Ids to an @future method that would then check to see if WhoId or WhatId was populated and perform logic.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000095HTIAY

Comment: Can you assist with my @future method? I am getting null pointer exceptions on odd lines, one on a system.debug line

Comment: Need to see code?

Comment: Thank you for posting the workaround. I'm having the issue of having null WhoId on the Task record. The flow of action is as follows: Outlook "Add Email" --> Standard Task creation --> Task trigger --> Apex code `@future` method My Task trigger calls a `@future` method in an Apex class. I'm seeing the null WhoId in the Apex `@future` method, not in the trigger itself. So I'm not sure how your proposed workaround works in this scenario. What happens if the WhoId and WhatId are still detected null in the `@future` method? Do you have a loop that keeps calling the `@future` method with the Task a

Answer (score 0):

Nerrissa,

I just discovered the same issue and I think I can help you out.

Basically you need your trigger to determine whether the who and what Id are null - NOT your apex class.

Example:

```
trigger TaskTrigger on Task (after insert, after update) {
    if (trigger.isAfter && TriggerHandler.firstRunTaskAfterTrigger) {
        //On After Insert 
        if(trigger.isInsert) {
            Set<Id> tasksWithBlankWhoAndWhatId = new Set<Id>();

            for (Task task : trigger.new) {             
                if(trigger.newMap.get(task.Id).WhoId == null && trigger.newMap.get(task.Id).WhatId == null)
                    tasksWithBlankWhoAndWhatId.add(task.Id);
            }

            try {
                TaskUpdateActivityInfo.determineObjTypeSFO(tasksWithBlankWhoAndWhatId);
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                for (Task task : trigger.new) {
                    system.debug('after insert error: ' + e.getMessage());
                    task.adderror(e.getMessage());          
                }
            }   
        }
```

Then your class should have a method like this:

```
public with sharing class TaskUpdateActivityInfo {      
    @future 
    public static void determineObjTypeSFO(Set<Id> taskIdsForProcessing) {
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.